# Datables row color based on checkbox value

Tags: datatables

Ok, what if I want to change row color based on the value of a checkbox in the datatable? I can't seem to get the syntax correct. e.g below value of data[9] does not work. I've tried 1 and true both with and without quotes. And with `rowCallback` also. data[7] works fine either way. I'm sure its the derivation of the data[9] checkbox value, seen nothing on this.

```
createdRow: function (row, data, index) {
    if (data[9] == 'checked') {
        $('td', row).css('background-color', 'Red');
    }
    else if (data[7] == '$6') {
        $('td', row).css('background-color', 'Orange');
    }
}
```

First post, apologies for formatting

I've discovered this workaround for me, but there must be a better way:

```
      createdRow: function (row, data, index) {
                if (data[9] == '<input checked="checked" class="check-box" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox">') {
                    $('td', row).css('background-color', 'Red');
                }
                else if (data[7] == '$6') {
                    $('td', row).css('background-color', 'Orange');
                }
            }
```

Comment: I've discovered this workaround for me, but there has to be a better way:

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

The render function is used to get the value to display (html), retrieve the data, sort and filter. So you must return different values for each operation (which is determined by the `type` attribute.

Now, in the snippet, the value return for retrieving is the value of the column and not the html to display it. The createdRow function gets the data from those render functions, so it no longer gets the HTML

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#myTable').DataTable({
        data: [[5, true], [3, false]],
        columns:[
          {data:0},
          {
            data:1,
            render: function(data, type, row, meta){
                // if type is not "display", it means that we want to sort, filter,
                // or retrieve data, so we return the value
                if (type !== "display")
                    return data;
                
                // We return the HTML we want to display now that we are sure
                return `<input class="check-box" ${data?'checked="checked"':''} type="checkbox">` 
            }
          }
        ],
        createdRow: function (row, data, index){
            // Now that we have the data and not the HTML it is cleaner
            if (data[1])
              $('td', row).css('background-color', 'Red');
        }
        
    });
} );
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="myTable">
</table>
```

PD.: It is better to create a DOM node with jQuery and check the property "disabled" that comparing the HTML

Comment: Take a look to this aswell https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns saved me in several occasions

Comment: Thanks very much folks. I'll look at all these and see if they present a faster and/or more reusable technique.

Comment: Ups. sorry, I read `disabled` instead of `checked`. Changing the properties should work. I apply teh change to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Parse the string into a jquery object using `parseHTML` and then check if it's checked.

```
createdRow: function (row, data, index) {
    if ($($.parseHTML(data[9])).is(":checked")) {
        $('td', row).css('background-color', 'Red');
    }
    else if (data[7] == '$6') {
        $('td', row).css('background-color', 'Orange');
    }
}
```